# Firebase retrieve user image with user ID

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I currently have this function to retrieve the current user image image url, but i want o use user id instead of currentUser how can this be done. Everything work well with the code but i just want to be able to use the function on other users also

```
func ProfileImage(imageUIView:UIImageView,borderColor:UIColor,borderWidth:CGFloat,backgroundColor:UIColor,noimageLabel:UILabel){



    if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser{

        if user.photoURL == ""{
                print("database image is not set")

            imageUIView.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
            imageUIView.layer.masksToBounds = false
            imageUIView.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
            imageUIView.layer.cornerRadius = imageUIView.frame.height/2
            imageUIView.clipsToBounds = true
            imageUIView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
            noimageLabel.hidden = false


        }else{

            imageUIView.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
            imageUIView.layer.masksToBounds = false
            imageUIView.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
            imageUIView.layer.cornerRadius = imageUIView.frame.height/2
            imageUIView.clipsToBounds = true
            imageUIView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
            noimageLabel.hidden = true

            var imageUrl = NSData(contentsOfURL: user.photoURL!)

            imageUIView.image = UIImage(data: imageUrl!)

        }

    }




}
```

Answer (score 2):

More information about your Firebase data's structure is necessary to give a complete answer but I can guide you on the right path.

As long as your user's are stored with unique identifiers as their keys, you can use this reference to retrieve the url for their profile picture.

```
var userRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(<url to user ids> + "\(unique user id)") // this creates a FIRDatabase ref to the specified user id
userRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, :withBlock: { (snapshot)
   // perform desired functionallity with the image URL from the specified user
})
```

Hope this is helps!

Comment: Like this you are not able to see other user profiles because you do not know the UID.